# Why this ambiguous behaviour of "printf()"?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I have intentionally forced `printf()` to print `celsius` as an `int` (Using `%8d` format specifier for it). I know that this is the reason of printing `0` (under the heading `Celsius Scale`).

But I just want to know why `fahr` is going to be printing `0.0` in the whole table.

I have used GCC compiler.

This is the code for **Celsius to Fahrenheit Conversion** :

```
#define LOWER 0.0F
#define UPPER 300.0F
#define STEP 20.0F

#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    float celsius, fahr;
    printf("*Conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit*\n");
    printf("Celsius Scale \t   Fahrenheit Scale\n");
    for (celsius = LOWER; celsius <= UPPER; celsius = celsius + STEP) {
        fahr = (9.0f * celsius / 5.0f) + 32.0f; 
        printf("%8d\t\t%5.1f\n", celsius, fahr);
    }
}
```

This following table is the **output** of the above code :

```
*Conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit*
Celsius Scale      Fahrenheit Scale
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
       0                  0.0
```

Answer (score 6):

You have **undefined behaviour** (which means it is not 'predictable' what the results of an operation will be), as you are passing a `float` argument to `printf` when it expects an `int` argument (for the `%8d`) format.

From this [C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions**
>   ...
>   9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any
>   argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion
>   specification, the behavior is undefined.

Exactly *why* the `fahr` values are shown incorrectly is difficult to say with any certainty, but it's *possibly* connected to the fact the the `float` arguments are promoted to `double`, which has a different size than the expected `int` type, and thus, the call stack (or call 'frame' if arguments are passed in registers) is corrupted.

*It is perhaps worth noting that, on my system (MSVC, 64-bit), running your code displays zeros for the `celsius` fields but the **correct** values for `fahr`. (But compiling for a 32-bit target **does** reproduce your problem!)*

To fix the problem, explicitly cast the `celsius` argument to an `int`:

```c
void main()
{
    float celsius, fahr;
    printf("*Conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit*\n");
    printf("Celsius Scale \t   Fahrenheit Scale\n");
    for (celsius = LOWER; celsius <= UPPER; celsius = celsius + STEP) {
        fahr = (9.0f * celsius / 5.0f) + 32.0f;
        printf("%8d\t\t%5.1f\n", (int)celsius, fahr);
    }
}
```

Comment: (a) When the C standard says behavior is “undefined,” it only means the C standard imposes no requirements. It does not mean nothing imposes any requirements and therefore does not mean anything can happen. Other specifications and limitations still apply.

Comment: (b) In common C implementations (and ABIs generally), the first few integer and floating-point arguments are passed in different sets of registers. So when a floating-point value is passed but an integer is expected, the value is read from an integer register. “0” is printed if the register happens to contain zero. This is not related to the promotion of ‘`float` to `double` and  does not corrupt the call stack *per se*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair comments. I have edited the answer to address (hopefully) your points.

Comment: @usr the C standard no longer requires it to do so though.

Comment: There are numerous instances here on Stack Overflow where folks have (humorously) suggested that Undefined Behaviour can (e.g.) "wipe your hard disk" or (sic) "spray your cat pink." However, as others (esp. @EricPostpischil) have pointed out, it's not *quite* as dire as that.

Comment: @AdrianMole, yes, I rather enjoy the humurous approaches to the concept of undefined behavior, on the other hand, I've also experienced Eric's rath :) when it comes to play aronund with it so I keep a reserved stance on that matter.

Comment: @anastaciu I think Eric's stance is correct for *answers* (which should be both accurate and precise). However, comments are a rather different species.

Comment: @AdrianMole, yes, agreed.

Answer (score 4):

As for the issue with `fahr` I tried to reproduce in several versions of GCC, but I was not able to, which is not unexpected since undefined behavior is exactly that, undefined, one cannot expect consistent results. I can try with the version and the exact compilation command you used, but I don't expect it to make a difference.

For instance [in this sample code](https://godbolt.org/z/SCfNin) the results are totally different from yours.

For a `double` or `float` variable, as you know, you need  `"%f"` specifier, you can cast `celsius` to `int` as was already mentioned or remove the `0`s with the specifier itself:

```
printf("%8.0f\t\t%5.1f\n", celsius, fahr);
         ^^^
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/JhfYgW)

Note that using this method will round the values instead of truncating them.

Output:

```
*Conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit*
Celsius Scale      Fahrenheit Scale
       0                 32.0
      20                 68.0
      40                104.0
      60                140.0
      80                176.0
     100                212.0
     120                248.0
     140                284.0
     160                320.0
     180                356.0
     200                392.0
     220                428.0
     240                464.0
     260                500.0
     280                536.0
     300                572.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is precise: *I just want to know why fahr is going to be printing 0.0 in the whole table.*

As you already understand, you have undefined behavior because you pass a `float`, which is actually converted to a `double`, to `printf` as an argument for which `printf` expects an `int`. Anything can happen, you get `0` and `0.0` as output for all lines, you could have gotten pretty much anything else or a crash...

To try and explain your observations, you must look into what is actually happening on your very system for this code. Such an analysis requires in depth knowledge on your system, ABI, compiler, compiler options, etc.

I modified your code and compiled it with [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/44JDip) and here are my observations for 2 configurations:

## gcc version 9.3 for intel 64-bits, with optimisations disabled.

The code for the erroneous `printf` in 64-bits is this:

```
    cvtss2sd        xmm1, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    cvtss2sd        xmm0, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC6
    mov     eax, 2
    call    printf
```

The code for the a modified argument `(int)celcius` which is what `printf` expects:

```
    cvtss2sd  xmm0, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    movss     xmm1, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cvttss2si eax, xmm1
    mov       esi, eax
    mov       edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC6
    mov       eax, 1
    call      printf
```

In the 64-bit version, the erroneous code passes `celcius` and `fahr` as `double` values in floating point registers `%xmm0` and `%xmm1` respectively and passes the value `2` in `%eax`, whereas the correct code would pass `fahr` as a `double` in `%xmm0` and `celcius` converted to an `int` in register `%esi`, and the value `1` in `%eax`.

The value in `%eax`, more precisely the contents of `%al` is the number of vector registers used to pass arguments. To implement the vararg api in `printf`, the compiler generates a prolog that uses this value to save the register arguments to the stack:

```
myprintf:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 104
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-216], rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-168], rsi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-160], rdx
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-152], rcx
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-144], r8
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-136], r9
    test    al, al
    je      .L12
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-128], xmm0
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-112], xmm1
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-96], xmm2
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-80], xmm3
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-64], xmm4
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-48], xmm5
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-32], xmm6
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm7
.L12:
```

So `printf` will read from `[rbp-216]` the `int` value expected for the `%8d` format and from `[rbp-128]` the `double` value for `fahr`.
The `int` value will be whatever `%rsi` happened to contain when `printf` was called, `0` from your observations. The `double` value should be whatever was passed in `xmm0`, so you would expect to see the value of `celcius`, and that's indeed what I observe on my system. Since you observe something quite different, there is a good chance your system does not use this 64-bit ABI.

## gcc version 9.3 for intel 32-bits, with optimisations disabled.

In 32 bits, the arguments are all passed on the stack. When passing 2 `float` values, we have:

```
    fld     DWORD PTR [ebp-12]
    fld     DWORD PTR [ebp-16]
    sub     esp, 12
    lea     esp, [esp-8]
    fstp    QWORD PTR [esp]
    lea     esp, [esp-8]
    fstp    QWORD PTR [esp]
    push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC6
    call    printf
    add     esp, 32
```

and when passing an `int` and a `float`:

```
    fld     DWORD PTR [ebp-16]
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [ebp-12]
    cvttss2si       eax, xmm0
    lea     esp, [esp-8]
    fstp    QWORD PTR [esp]
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC6
    call    printf
    add     esp, 16
```

So `printf` expects the `int` at `[ebp+12]` and the `double` at `[ebp+16]` but instead `celcius` was pushed as a `doouble` at `[ebp+12]` and `fahr` at `[ebp+20]`.

The `int` read from `[ebp+12]` are in fact the 4 low order bytes of the `celcius` value.  Since the `celcius` values are small integers, the 32 low order bits of their 64-bit floating point representation are all zeroes, hence the integer read is `0`. Conversely, the `double` value read for `fahr` is misaligned: the first 4 bytes are the high 32-bits of the `double` value of `celcius` and the last 4 bytes are the low 32 bits of the `double` value `fahr`, which are 0 because `fahr` is also a small integral value. Hence the exponent part of this `double` value has all bits zero, so it is either the value `0.0` or an extremely small denormal value that converts to `0.0` with the `%5.1f` conversion format. Indeed I get the same output as you do in 32-bit mode.

You can experiment with a different format such as `%g` for `fahr` and check if my prediction for a very small value is correct.

Of course this forensic study is only relevant to a specific architecture and by no means condoned by the C Standard.